# I'm trying to have 8 items on a bootstrap row - I was wondering if this is possible?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put 8 items on a bootstrap row and it doesn't seem that bootstrap takes something.5 or a row (e.g col-md-1.5). Is there any way around this? This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
   <div class = "col-lg-1.5 text-center">


  <img src = "" alt = ""/>

  </div>

  ... //8 more columns here
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your options are: 1. create something that fits 12 columns. 2. set a offset, 3. create your own classes

Answer (score 0):

Make a row and place inside two cols, (col-lg-6 in your case). Inside that cols make another row and place another 4 (col-lg-3).

The option using an offset as @Escobear says it's good too, but in your case you need better precision and you can't fit enough offsets to make it proporcional